# How to save an image to database using SQLite and PHP?

Tags: php, database, image, sqlite

I want to save an image to the database using SQLite. I send the image via `<input type='file'>` in HTML, get the file in the `$_FILES` var in PHP, and after this, what I should do?

I created a `BLOB` field in the database. Currently I'm using SQLite 2.1, because that is the limitation of my homework.

Should I convert an image to binary to store in a database or do something else?

Comment: You may want to consider storing the files on the filesystem, and then storing the image name/path in your database. Makes management easier down the road.

Comment: Because it's a homework, I need to store in the database.

Comment: @ben: i don't think that makes the management easier.

Comment: @yes: I would argue for it because it gives me full access to my image store without needed to go into a db and select bytes to save as an image.

Comment: @Ben: actually to get access to your image in your case you need Access to your DB then access your File System. While storing into DB you just need the access to DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do `$image = file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );`

And then upload it into your blob column (of course it needs to be escaped before, PDO)

Comment: I used an base64_encode to write the data to the database after this.